# How would I go about uploading a python based file converter/parser to the web?

Tags: python, django, parsing, text-parsing

I have written a python script that takes a text file and reorganizes the information in the file. It takes out certain pieces of information and moves others. So basically it converts it. I want the simplest possible web interface that people can visit. On this interface there is a button to upload a your file then the interface runs this script on it and puts the output file on a new page or the same one for viewing or download. What would be the easiest way to do this? Should I look into Django? I feel like this is so basic that I almost don't need a web framework. I am basically just looking for some good keywords to google for this or other resources. What would this tool be called in web-lingo? Would a framework (django, ect.) help me out that much or is there a way to just basically have an html upload form that calls the python script?

Comment: Django isn't worth your trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could use raw [WSGI](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) (the newer way) or [Python's `cgi` module](http://docs.python.org/2/cgi.html) (perhaps more *traditional*), you might want to look into some *minimal* web frameworks built on top of WSGI. Here are a few:

- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)
- [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/)
- [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/)
- [web.py](http://www.webpy.org/)

They're all pretty simple to set up and get started with.
Pick one and figure out how to do whatever you need.

Comment: I would add bottle to the mix.  Very similar to flask, but even more minimal.

Answer (score 1):

[Utility Mill](http://utilitymill.com/) makes this kind of utility packaging very easy.